# Is it enough to only backup and restor KeyCloak's database?

Tags: docker, mariadb, keycloak

I'm using [KeyCloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak) for my next application's identity and access management, and I use their [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) image for this purpose.

Basically, I create a `docker-compose.yml` file with three services:

- KeyCloak
- MariaDb
- phpMyAdmin

And I set secure passwords for mariadb and admin user. I'm running this `docker-compose.yml` file on my personal VPS.

Thus I'm using KeyCloak in [Standalon Mode](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/14.0.0/server/README.md#usage)

Now, KeyCloak's [docs](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/14.0.0/server/README.md) for containers talks about exporting and importing realms.

However, I would prefer to only backup/restore databases and keep all of my data in databases in my applications.

I searched by found nothing in this regards.

Is it safe to only backup/restore KeyCloak's database? In my case, is it safe that I only backup/restore my MariaDB database? Or does KeyCloak keep state in other places too?

Can I only backup/restore mariadb database and forget about exporting/importing realms?

Comment: What is your concrete use case for export or backup?  In which case would you do an import or restore?

Comment: @sventorben, I didn't understand you fully. But my plan is to backup users database (in this case KeyCloak database) each hour, and put it on a cloud storage automatically. And in case I change my VPS, or in case of  a disaster, I would restore the last database.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it should be sufficient to backup your database. There is no need to import/export anything in that case. But be aware of the fact that some runtime data will only be stored in non-persistent caches (e.g. session, authenticationSessions etc.). Check the [docs here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/server_installation/#cache) for details.

That said, make sure you also backup your system configuration (e.g. any scripts you use for configuring the container).

Comment: are you part of KeyCloak's team? I mean, how do you know this with certainty?

Comment: No, I am not, though contributed some bugfixes ;)
The company I work for advises various Keycloak customers. So, I am quite sure about this.